# Yii how to exclude or hide rows in ExtendedGridView

Tags: php, gridview, yii, expression

I cant figure out how exactly i can hide some specific rows from my dataprovider or result.

For example:

> $this->widget(
>      'bootstrap.widgets.TbExtendedGridView',
>      array(
>
> ```
>    'fixedHeader' => true,
>    'headerOffset' => 40,
>    'id'=>'my_grid',
>    'type' => 'striped',
>    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
>    'responsiveTable' => true,
>    'rowHtmlOptionsExpression' => function($data) {
>        // dont hide row function
>        if($data->id!=4)
>            // hide this row in grid OR even better dont parse it at all.
>        }
>    },
>    'template' => "{items}{summary}{pager}",
>    'columns' => $columns,
> ```
>
> ));

Comment: It would be better if you edit the query in your controller so that the dataprovider will not have the unwanted rows in the first place.

Comment: That was the first thing i was going to do. But i found out that it was almost impossible to do. Because of the many if / else statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were on the right path. [`rowHtmlOptionsExpression`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView#rowHtmlOptionsExpression-detail) needs a php expression that returns an array. Try

```
'rowHtmlOptionsExpression' => '($data->id==4?array("display"=>"none"):array()',
```

You should note that this will not affect the summary or pagination though since the row will still exist in html, hence @aggelgian's suggestion might be a better solution.